# How can one adjust each text to the center for each box of the table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

Here is the example:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X|X| }
\hline
Equation & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\
\hline
$y_0 = b^{t}$ & -483061 & 1 & -174089 & 793599 \\
\hline
$y_1 = y_0^{2}$ & -1 &  & 73782 & 77096 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

I tried `\centerline` between letters and `\center` after `\textwidth`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this!  It's my first time here, so I don't have much experience here as I do in Math Stack Exchange.  Hopefully, I won't forget. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `>{\centering}` before the relevant column, or more conveniently define a new column type as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |Z|Z|Z|Z|Z|Z| }
\hline
Equation & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 \\
\hline
$y_0 = b^{t}$ & -483061 & 1 & -174089 & 793599 \\
\hline
$y_1 = y_0^{2}$ & -1 &  & 73782 & 77096 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```